# How can I fix bluetooth issues which are affecting booting time?

Tags: boot, grub2, bluetooth, xubuntu

I've recently installed xubuntu 17.10. I noticed some error messages while booting. Here's the my `dmesg` output(only errors and their previous lines):

```
...  
[   13.717201] usb 5-3: USB disconnect, device number 2  
[   15.164286] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc20 tx timeout  
...  
[   20.756846] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized  
[   23.260344] Bluetooth: hci0: download fw command failed (-110)
```

The line with [ 15.164286] and [ 23.260344] are shown in red(errors) on my console. I doubt this is what slowing down the boot process(approx. 5 secs). How can I solve this issue?
Edit: My `lsmod` output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rndis_host             16384  0
cdc_ether              16384  1 rndis_host
usbnet                 45056  2 rndis_host,cdc_ether
bnep                   20480  2
arc4                   16384  2
rtl8723ae              94208  0
btcoexist             131072  1 rtl8723ae
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723ae
rtl_pci                32768  1 rtl8723ae
snd_hda_codec_realtek    98304  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
rtlwifi                77824  4 rtl_pci,btcoexist,rtl8723_common,rtl8723ae
snd_hda_intel          40960  4
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
kvm_amd              2179072  0
kvm                   589824  1 kvm_amd
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
mac80211              782336  2 rtl_pci,rtlwifi
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
cdc_acm                32768  0
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
joydev                 20480  0
bluetooth             544768  11 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,btusb
sparse_keymap          16384  0
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
input_polldev          16384  0
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
i2c_piix4              24576  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
k10temp                16384  0
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_pci_ms
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              614400  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
shpchp                 36864  0
snd                    81920  19 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
amdkfd                188416  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
radeon               1478656  3
psmouse               147456  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 radeon
ttm                    94208  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper        167936  1 radeon
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  86016  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mii                    16384  2 r8169,usbnet
sdhci_pci              28672  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_pci
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                32768  1 ahci
drm                   360448  6 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
rtsx_pci               57344  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
wmi                    24576  0
video                  40960  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try disabling the bluetooth service (sudo systemctl disable bluetooth) to see if it helps. Another step you could take is figuring out which module is loaded for bluetooth support and blacklist that module, which should prevent the error.
Add a line `blacklist bluetooth` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` , if the module doesn't depend on others. If it does depend on others, add a line `install bluetooth /bin/false` instead. Check [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_module#Using_files_in_.2Fetc.2Fmodprobe.d.2F_2) for more info.